# How can I use SFTP to transfer a directory to my local PC, but make the transfered directory have a different name on my local PC?

Tags: directory, sftp

I'm going to do a reinstall on my laptop and want to backup my .config. But the issue is that when I tried to do it I think it replaced my desktops .config because they both have the exact same path.(Luckily I keep my desktop and laptops configuration VERY similar, so I'm not noticing any issues immediately) Which is why I want to force the downloaded directory to have a different name so it doesn't try to replace the files on my desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply provide a different directory name as destination to the `sftp` command, e.g.:

```
sftp -r user@host:~/.config .config_backup
```

Comment: I didn't actually realize that you could get files like that, I always have just done "sftp IP" and used get to transfer files. I should have expected that you could do it that way though because that would make sense. Thanks.